# "Insufficient Permission" at Google Storage API

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, authorization

I have written a Google Storage client (using OAuth 2.0).

I've created `client_id`/`client_secret` in the dashboard.

My Web application redirects me to authorize myself in Google, requests an access token from Google, and then queries Google with this access token.

Google responds to a `PUT` request (`$ua->put("https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/victor-porton/o/test.txt?uploadType=media&name=test.txt", Content => $State)`):

```
403 Forbidden
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Manual uploading of files to this cloud storage button does work.

What I did wrong? How to add permissions to my `client_id`?

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I tried to use an URL for GET requests for POST requests (and also used PUT in place of POST, what is the second error).

I should follow https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

I've corrected it and it works now.